# I cannot choose between iGPU and GPU. Why?

Tags: gpu, integrated-graphics

So when I had my old laptop with discrete GPU, I always had a choice in Windows right-click menu. For example, I could choose which app should run Adobe Photoshop or certain game.

Now I have a PC with both integrated (Intel HD graphics) and discrete GPU (geforce 730), but there is no option which GPU should run which apps. Why is that?

Comment: Did you make sure to install current drivers? If you only have the basic drivers that are automatically downloaded via Windows Update you might not have all features available.

Comment: Yes, I did install the last driver from nvidia's site.

Comment: have you enabled both in BIOS?

Comment: Yes. There is an option in BIOS called Multi GPU and I did enable it.

Answer (score 1):

Desktops are not as power limited as laptops and are not assumed to be needed to work in this configuration.

Doing this kind of active switching will require some kind of hardware support for the feature and means that your dedicated GPU output would have to be fed back to your iGPU or you have to have a lot of complicated multiplexing of outputs going on.

From the Nvidia Optimus Whitepaper the image below shows how the system is wired up.

[image]

This means that you would not be using the display outputs from your graphics card and instead you would have to render on the dGPU, pass the rendered image data to the iGPU and then display it. Not using the 3 or more outputs on the graphics card would limit you to however many outputs are on your motherboard. Having only one display would be a deal breaker for many people.

Otherwise motherboard manufacturers would have to integrate 3 or more display outputs that until this point have always been on the graphics card. This would complicate the matter or wiring and routing the motherboard.

For the high end gamers the extra delay of rendering then transferring data to the iGPU for display rather than the graphics card immediately displaying it itself could be unacceptable.

There was apparently a Desktop Optimus solution [slated for release back in 2011,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus#cite_note-4) but never made it to market. Presumably this was due to lack of demand and lack of support from manufacturers who saw it as unnecessary when the power efficiency is less of a concern.

As a result both the iGPU and dGPU are considered to be completely independent on desktop systems and have very little of the integration that is seen on laptops.

Comment: So you're telling me there are no options? But right now even Google Chrome runs through discrete GPU. I don't want it to... What can I do?

Comment: You can connect your monitor (or an extra monitor) to the iGPU motherboard connector to use that GPU...

Comment: But when I do this, I cannot use discrete GPU :(

Comment: No; There isn't a solution to this problem.

Comment: @Anton it feels like something is missing from your question. I've told you that you do not get the same choice on desktop systems and why, but I cannot see why you would *need* the choice in the first place. Laptops have that option so that they can save power and extend battery life by turning off the high power dGPU when the iGPU is enough, desktops very rarely need that compromise. Why *exactly* do you need that option?

Answer (score -1):

I am able to brute force the GPU affinity on a fresh windows 10 install using a NVIDIA GTX 960 and 8700k i7 coffee lake. You won't like how I did it:

- Uninstall primary device driver, I.E. Your GPU. The iGPU is now your primary device.
- Load up all applications that you want on the iGPU. Since this is the only device it will be used.
- Reinstall your GPU driver. On a desktop this is immediately set up to be the default device.
- All new applications are forced to use the primary device.

That's all there is to it! Every time you want a program to use the iGPU affinity just nuke your primary display driver and load it up.

Comment: I very much doubt this actually does what you think it does. Without drivers, Windows will simply use the default graphics driver. *Some* software may be able to use the iGPU for some tasks, but in the end it’s like Mokubai described: Because the display pipelines are entirely separate, you can’t use the iGPU to draw accelerated content on other screens.