# Using iGPU with discrete GPU yielding worse GPU performance

Tags: performance, switchable-graphics

I have an AMD Ryzen 7 4800h CPU with AMD Radeon Graphics as well as an Nvidia GTX 1650, all installed on a Lenovo Legion 5.

I noticed that when I boot with the iGPU (AMD Radeon Graphics) and use the discrete GPU (Nvidia GTX 1650) for a game, I experience worse performance than if I were to boot with the dedicated GPU alone. When I fire up the application, both GPUs increase in active time, although I assigned the application to the Nvidia GPU.

The application I am trying to use is an undemanding FPS shooter is called [Valorant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valorant) on low graphics settings. When running with the iGPU enabled in BIOS, I get around 100 less frames, although task manager still says I am using dedicated graphics for the game.

- I have tested this using manufacturer drivers and generic drivers. The GPU is using dedicated GPU RAM for the application.
- I have configured the application to use the dedicated GPU through Windows' Graphics Settings.
- I have attempted to research this and I believe it has something to do with the discrete GPU sending images to the iGPU which is directly (I think) connected to my display.
- I am wondering why this is happening. If you can, please elaborate with me on this topic.

Comment: Might be worth it for you to share what game you are having issues with. This could be a game specific issue.

Comment: Oh, okay. The FPS Shooter is called VALORANT. When running with the iGPU enabled in BIOS, I get around 100 less frames, although task manager still says I am using dedicated graphics for the game.

Comment: Have you taken a look in `dxdiag` or Intel Graphics Command Center?

Comment: I will look into dxdiag now thanks. Also I am using an AMD Mobile CPU with an NVIDIA GPU so I do not have intel graphics command center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was researching today and found an answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1234979/i-cannot-choose-between-igpu-and-gpu-why)

Although this question applies to a desktop, I believe it also applies to this situation and what I am experiencing here. The GPU passes rendered frames to the iGPU for it to be displayed. Apparently the delay between passing it to the iGPU all the way to the display is what seems to be causing this performance dip.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going into the Nvidia display properties and telling it to use the dedicated GPU in there for the game?

I'm on a desktop, but I think on a laptop an option appears to select which GPU to use per game:

[image: Screenshot of the options.]

Also, some games will let you manually select which GPU to use, have you tried that?

I know that on some laptops if you plug in an external display via the HDMI or DisplartPort ports, then it can force the use of the dedicated GPU, but as far as I know just using the internal screen shouldn't cause any decrease in performance?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I have done this, that did not work, so I also did it at the O.S. level. In task manager it is telling me that it is indeed using my discrete GPU, however the performance is far less great compared to booting without the iGPU enabled.